# Jasmine: mock method response based on method's parameters

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy

My question is simple. I want to mock a method ONLY if a certain value is passed to the method. Something like this:

```
spyOn(myObj, "getUser").and.withArgs('userA').and.returnValue(null);
```

If the method getUser is invoked with the value 'userA', the method should return null.

Is that possibly with Jasmine? I'm using Karma with ***jasmine-core": "^2.6.1*** and ***jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1"***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking advantage of `callFake`:

```
spyOn(myObj, 'getUser').and.callFake(arg => {
  if(arg === 'userA') {
    return null;
  } else {
    return 'hello'; // it is up to you what to return if it is not 'userA'
  }
});
```